# Contact Form 7 - Add Ev

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I'd like to add Event Tracking to the Submit button but don't understand where to access that in the plug-in files for this Wordpress plugin called Contact Form 7.

If it was HTML, I'd replace something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

With something like this:

```
<input onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Send']);" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the code of your plugin by logging into your WP site, clicking "Plugins" on the left, scrolling down to the name of your plugin "Contact Form 7", and clicking "Edit."  There will probably be a list of file on the right, and in the main part of the screen it will have opened the first one.  The trick is just figuring out where that particular code is.  I would suggest doing Ctrl+F on `value="Send"`.  Even better yet if the input is inside something with an ID or something.